# Jquery mobile output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a simple  Pension calculator. Three inputs are taken in one form page and the result is displayed in another page. Output is in text format. But the following problem happens:

The output is shown as e.g. 2100021000 instead of actual 21000 this happens in all calculated results.

1. How to display results properly without the repeats ?
2. How do I display results in three separate text boxes in the results page similar to the text input form page ? I'm new to this. Need help.

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<title>Pension Calculator</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js1/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js1/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
// Bind to 'pageinit' event for our data page
//$(document).delegate('#data', 'pageinit', function(){
     $(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function() {
     // Do some processing when the button with id 'calc' is clicked or tapped

    $('#calc').bind('click', function() {
        //event.preventDefault();
          var basic = $('[name="basic"]').val(),
              pbasic = $('[name="pbasic"]').val(),
              gratuity = $('[name="gratuity"]').val(),
              da = $('[name="da"]').val(),
              years = $('[name="years"]').val(),
              total = $('[name="total"]').val(),


     basic = basic + (basic*da/100);
     pbasic = basic/2;     
     da = pbasic*da/100;
     gratuity = (basic) + ((da))*15/26 * years;

    if  
        (gratuity > 1000000)

        gratuity = 10000000;        

    total = (pbasic) + (da);
    gratuity = gratuity.toFixed(2);
    pbasic = pbasic.toFixed(2);
    total = total.toFixed(2);

      // Get to the DOM node that has the actual BMI text
          //  while ($total.children().length) {
              //  $total = $total.children().first();


            // Set it to the calculated value
           // $total.text(total);


              $result = $('#results #gratuity');
              $result.text(gratuity);


              $result = $('#results #pbasic');
              $result.text(pbasic);


              $result = $('#results #total');
              $result.text(total);





    });   
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>Simple Pension Calculator</h1>  

</header>

<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">


    <div data-role="content">

    <form id="theForm">


        <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-inset="true">

         <label for="basic">Present Basic (Basic including Grade Pay + NPA)</label>
                <input type="number" name="basic" id="basic" value="0" autofocus required>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="years">Years of Service</label>
                <input type="number" name="years" id="years" value="0" required>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="da">Existing DA (%)</label>
                <input type="number" name="da" id="da" value="0" required>
            </div>
            </form>
            <a id="calc" href="#results" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Calculate</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<div id="results" data-url="results" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Results</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
Your Gratuity:<br>
<span id="gratuity"><span style="font-size: 52px; "><strong>24</strong></span></span><br>
Your Basic Pension:<br>
<span id="pbasic"><span style="font-size: 52px; "><strong>24</strong></span></span><br>
Your Pension:<br><br>
<span id="total"><span style="font-size: 52px; "><strong>24</strong></span></span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `name=gratuity` and `name=pbasic` in html? Why are you using the same var `$result` 3 times?

Comment: As both gratuity and pbasic are calculated values so they are not in the input form. I use it three times to get outputs 1. gratuity 2. pbasic & 3. Penasion.

Comment: name=gratuity and name=pbasic are calculated values so they are not in the html input form. $result 3 times to get the calculated values of 1. gratuity 2. pbasic & 3. Pension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up your code like this:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Simple Pension Calculator</h1>  
    </header>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form id="theForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-inset="true">
                <label for="basic">Present Basic (Basic including Grade Pay + NPA)</label>
                <input type="number" name="basic" id="basic" value="0" autofocus required />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="years">Years of Service</label>
                <input type="number" name="years" id="years" value="0" required />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="da">Existing DA (%)</label>
                <input type="number" name="da" id="da" value="0" required />
            </div>
        </form>
        <a id="calc" href="#results" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Calculate</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="results" data-url="results" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Results</h1>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        Your Gratuity:<br />
        <span id="gratuity" class="resultspan"></span><br />
        Your Basic Pension:<br />
        <span id="pbasic"  class="resultspan"></span><br />
        Your Pension:<br />
        <span id="total" class="resultspan"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style the results span with CSS class instead of inline:

```
.resultspan {
    font-size: 52px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In the script, pbasic, gratuity and total are not read from the DOM but rather set during calculation, so initialize them to zero. When reading other values from the inputs, you can use `parseInt()` to ensure the text is converted to integers before using them in the calculations:

```
$('#calc').on('click', function() {        
    //event.preventDefault();
      var basic = parseInt($('#basic').val()),
          da = parseInt($('#da').val()),
          years = parseInt($('#years').val()),
          pbasic = 0,
          gratuity = 0,
          total = 0;

     basic = basic + (basic*da/100);
     pbasic = basic/2;     
     da = pbasic*da/100;
     gratuity = (basic) + ((da))*15/26 * years;

    if (gratuity > 1000000)
        gratuity = 10000000;        

    total = (pbasic) + (da);
    gratuity = gratuity.toFixed(2);
    pbasic = pbasic.toFixed(2);
    total = total.toFixed(2);


    $('#results #gratuity').text(gratuity);
    $('#results #pbasic').text(pbasic);
    $('#results #total').text(total);
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/f4rthqed/)**

Comment: Thank you ezanker so much. It is working now. How do I get the results to show in text boxes in the results page similar to input text boxes ?

Comment: @ranjan, Just use inputs instead of spans and write to .val() instead of .text(): http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/f4rthqed/1/

Comment: you make it so simple. Thank you very much. As I'm self taught please suggest me some books from where I can learn exactly what you suggested. Thank you once again.

Comment: @ranjan, If the answer helped, please accept it so future searchers will know the problem was solved. I don't have any book recommendations, but you could look at online resources such as these: http://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/10/21/so-you-want-to-be-a-programmer-huh-heres-25-ways-to-learn-online/

Comment: Made the following cosmetic changes. But cannot add footer. Tried in many ways but could not make it work. Moreover cannot even add an about page.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's all in the divisions where I got it wrong. It's a single page html with embedded multi pages. That's what I had missed. Pitfalls of a newbie I guess. Thanks again. Trying how to use data-direction="reverse".